# connect function block when a router cannot connect to internet

Tags: c, sockets, network-programming

I'm using the basic socket functions in C language, the line below:

```
int res = connect(sock_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
```

1. when my laptop is can access the internet, `connect` will return immediately,connection is built as expected.
2. when my laptop is offline, `connect` will return immediately, the errno is "network is unreachable.
3. when my laptop is connected to a wifi network that cannot access internet directly(need login opration or sth else), `connect` will block about 20 seconds before return, the errno is "connection refused"
It can be solved by set the sock_fd nonblocking, I want to know why it takes such a long time before `connect` return a connection mistake in the third situation?

Answer (score 1):

In the 2nd case (network offline), the operating system knows it is offline and so the network libraries can immediately signal a failure.

In the 3rd case (network online, but unable to reach internet)  the operating system thinks it is online, but has no way to tell that in advance that the connection won't succeed.  The actual failure mode depends on the nature of the network you are connected to:

- In the case you are experiencing, the network simply isn't responding at all to to your connection attempt.  Your packets are simply being ignored.  Eventually you experience a connection timeout, when the connect function gives up waiting for a response.   It is normal for it to wait some period of time before giving up, since not all connections on the internet happen instantly (network is slow or congested, or the server on the other end is slow to respond)
- In another case, a firewall might be configured to actively reject connections that are not allowed.   This means that it will send a packet back in response that says the connection was rejected.  If this happens you would quickly get an error back from connect().
- There is a third possibility... this is a situation where you are connected to a network that requires you to enter a password on a web page, or click to acknowledge that you acknowledge the policies for using the internet at that business.  No matter what internet site you are trying to access with your browser, you first see this page.   This is called a captive portal and is implemented by responding to port 80 traffic at any IP address and sending the login page instead.  If you were trying to connect a socket to port 80 (the http port) at any IP address, the connection would succeed (even though you are not actually connected to the remote server you expect).  If you are using a port other than port 80, it would instead ignore or block the connection.    I mention this in case you are trying to write a program that determines if you are connected to the internet or not.  Using port 80 wouldn't work well in this case.

Comment: thanks, can you recommand some books that can help me to dig deeper?